# How do you get events from a function in another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development, events

I have two contracts :

```
// contract #1
contract eXample {
// intizializer 
  function eXample{
   .....
  }
//creating the Event
  event MyEvent(uint x,uint y,uint z);
  function doSomething{
    .....
// calling the event inside doSomething function
   MyEvent(x,y,z);
  }
}


contract contractCaller {
  ....
// creating an instance of contract #1
  eXample instance = eXample(address)
 // calling fonction from contract #1 inside contract #2 method.
  function exampleFunction{
    instance.doSomething
  }
  // everytjing inside eXamplefunction is working. Everything inside instance.doSomething IS working. Only issue is the Event not triggering.
  ....
}
```

I'm using function from "eXample" in "contractCaller" everything works fine but one thing. When calling instance.doSomething from the 2nd contract i'm not returned any Event from the 1st contract in either mix/ on the blockchain.Obviously i have watchers,etc.

Is it normal ?
Should i make custom Events on my 2nd contract for functions on the first contract ?

How do you guys usually proceed ?

Edit better example since i messed up the first one :

```
contract metaCoin { 
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;
  function metaCoin() {
    balances[msg.sender] = 10000;
  }
  event ExampleEvent(uint x);
  function sendToken(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool successful){
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    ExampleEvent(balances[receiver]);
    return false;
  }
}

contract coinCaller{
  function sendCoin(address coinContractAddress, address receiver, uint amount){
    metaCoin m = metaCoin(coinContractAddress);
    m.sendToken(receiver, amount);
  }
}
```

When calling CoinCaller.Sendcoin. ExampleEvent won't trigger even with a watcher on the MetaCoin Contract.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Solidity code to me. What is MyCallback, and why do you expect it to be able to call the calling contract?

Comment: Mycallback is a callback in contract #1 , it's wrapped in a function " doSomething" that get called in contract #2, inside "exampleFunction".
When eXamplefunction get called by the user , it call the fonction from contract #1 (that do other things before the cb obv). It works. Only the callback doesn't get triggered when i have a watcher on contract #1 callbacks.
I'm not sure what doesn't look valid to you as it's only basic solidity , i've just quickly retyped an example case so maybe there are typos, other than that i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: as a general rule of thumb you'll get better answer by posting correct code as people might want to try it out. It's kind of difficult here

Comment: Yes i know. I'm just wondering if people know if callback are getting triggered when called from another contract i wasn't really asking for a fix to my contract. The example was provided to illustrate my question.

Comment: @user697 But the example isn't complete - it _doesn't_ work, so there's no way for us to tell whether the problem is your code or something else.

Comment: I've updated the original example earlier and added an new example in the edit. please check the edit for an better/clearer example

Comment: @user697 It's still neither correct nor complete - can you provide a simple case that actually parses as valid solidity code?

Comment: 2nd case is extremely simple and now works. I had a keyword missing. please have a look.

Comment: @user697 Okay, you need to include the code you're using to listen for the event, too. And if possible, link to a blockchain TX that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2):

Alright. Now. Your events should be logged in solidity but you have to call the event in JS to access the logged information. There's a whole section on these things in the web3 api. 
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events

Comment: or you can pass the contract by address

Comment: Good point. You could do that too.

Comment: I'm already using mix/christeh tool. It's mostly working , just the callback doesnt work. It's setup properly.  The contract calling contract is in the same file under the #1 contract.  I'm already refering to the contract by `address.  instance = eXample(address)` .
As i said already everything is working fine function wise. It's just the callback that doesn't trigger in JS. Everything else works perfectly fine.I'll add comment to the code so you can understand it better.

Comment: can you use a more specific example of your code with proper variables put in? Currently it's a bit of a mess and I'm having some difficulty helping you because I have to go and rewrite your code with some major assumptions along the way. Your callback should be a function no? Or did you mean to write it as an event? Just please...show us a little more code so we can help you.

Comment: ohh i see now why you don't understand. Yes my callback is an Event. My bad. I don't know why i kept calling events callbacks. I meant events not callbacks. I'll clean everything up

Comment: Alright. Editted my answer. That should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`msg.sender` is the sender of current call.

`tx.origin` is the [sender of the full call chain](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html?highlight=tx.origin#global-variables).

In the metaCoin example, you should use `tx.origin`.